# Spring:Error while accessing scoped beans from jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scope, session-variables, sitemesh

I learnt how to access session scoped sping beans from a jsp but got the following error:

`No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? scoped beans from jsp`

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("scopedTarget.otmSessionHolder")).getUserVO()
```

my web.xml:

```
 <listener>
            <description>Spring Context Listener</description>
            <display-name>Spring Context Listener</display-name>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <listener>
            <display-name>Request Context Listener</display-name>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <description>This Servlet intercepts all requests for this WebApplication</description>
            <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans/web/**/*-Beans.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>

<servlet>
        <description>This Servlet intercepts all requests for this WebApplication</description>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans/web/**/*-Beans.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet>
        <description>This Servlet intercepts all RESTful requests for this Web Application</description>
        <servlet-name>RESTfulSpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans/web/RESTful-Beans.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

But still I get this exception
I use sitemesh decorator for template.Have been going thru these forums,but to no avail.Kindly help me on this